# How to make sure that my direct3d application will run everytime on any PC

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

I have made an application which utilises Microsofts Directx9 as a graphics API, and it runs fine on my computer but on other computers, it asks for dlls mainly msvcrt and d3d runtime related. So how do I make sure that my application will run everytime someone executes it who doesn't know what vcrt or directx is? Do I supply the runtime packages with my app? Though it is not feasible for a 2MB application.  what to do?

Comment: Your application isn't 2MB in size. It is 2MB plus the size of all 3rd party libraries you are using. If you don't want users to enjoy your application, you could distribute an arbitrarily small fraction of your application just as well. If you do want your user to enjoy your application, you'll need to ship your application, in full.

Comment: [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416644%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is your friend

Answer (score 1):

As Nicol Bolas points out below, DirectX (and Visual C++) must be installed on the users machine for them to use your application.

I previously recommended bundling the [DirectX Web Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=35) because it pretty small, but as Ross Ridge mentioned, this might not be a legal way of distributing DirectX. Microsoft recommends to [not bundle the Web Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418797%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#always_install_directx__and_do_so_silently_), but use the redistributable package instead:

> Always Install DirectX, and Do So Silently
>
> It is strongly recommended that the game silently install the DirectX
>   redistributable that the game was built against. The DirectX
>   installation process is designed so that it verifies whether anything
>   needs to be updated and quickly returns if it doesn't. So, there is no
>   need to ask users if they want DirectX installed. A silent
>   installation of DirectX can be done by running this command from your
>   installation package: dxsetup.exe /silent
>
> Asking a user if he wants to install DirectX can cause many problems.
>   For example, if the user assumes he has the latest redistributable
>   installed and chooses to skip installation of DirectX; installation of
>   the game could continue successfully anyway. However, if the game
>   requires a specific version of D3DX, or other updated functionality
>   that was skipped, then the game won't work, and the user will be very
>   frustrated.

So please do as Microsoft recommends, and add the redistributable(s) to your application.

Also do not forget to include the license agreement of any redistributable to your application. These agreements **must** be presented and accepted by the user before installing.

Comment: @user3696177: So you don't want to distribute the stuff your users need with your application. And you don't want them to have to install it. So... what *do* you want? For the stuff your program needs to appear on user's systems by *magic*? Stuff has to be installed for D3D to work. So either your users install it, or your application's installer does. Or your program doesn't work.

Comment: Ok so which files should I distribute to make sure that my app runs? For directx 9 and 10